# JUnit : What is the default tolerance in asserEquals if the user does not specify any?

Tags: junit4

eg. If I use the function assertEquals(expected, actual) and dont define any tolerance what is the tolerance used by default.

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific, definitely no tolerance here.